# How long should the OAuth2 token live?

Tags: java, database, spring, oauth-2.0

What is the lifecycle of the OAuth2 token. Shall we persist it in a RDBMS for each user?

Comment: OAuth server already persists the token, do you want persist token in a Client?

Comment: isnt the idea of that token to be given only for the session?

Comment: Opinionated? now opinionated, after 2-3 years there will be a standard for that!! its opinionated but there is a best opinion!! that will become the standard in the future as with many other things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the **OAuth2** flow:

[image]

The Auth server sets the expiration date on the tokens, so you can use your token until it will expire.

Application receives an access token like this:

```
{"access_token":"ACCESS_TOKEN","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":2592000,"refresh_token":"REFRESH_TOKEN","scope":"read","uid":100101,"info":{"name":"Mark E. Mark","email":"mark@thefunkybunch.com"}}
```

When the token has expired if a refresh token was issued, it may be used to request new access tokens.

You can find more detail [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2).

Comment: So we cant manipulate the settings of the authorization server? Its managed by them? for example facebook, linkedIn.. we cant request tokens that live forever?

Comment: Nope, you can't manipulate the expiration date of the external auth server (facebook, github, linkedin etc..), but if you have your auth server you can do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize the lifecycle of the token (the original and the refresh token), for example in your implementation of `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` you can have:

```
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.inMemory().withClient("client-name")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT", "ROLE_ADMIN").scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .secret("secret").accessTokenValiditySeconds(15552000).refreshTokenValiditySeconds(30000000);
    }
```

and yes you can store the tokens in a RDBMS when you use in database management instead of in memory management of authentication and authorization.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the OAuth Provider but typically an access_token is valid for 1 hr and can be refreshed as long as you have the corresponding refresh_token pair. If the access_token has expired, then it can be refreshed using the refresh_token that was sent during the initial token request. Token should be deleted once the lifetime of refresh token is expired which can be typically very long duration in days or months.